# Change Sprite Position onAccelerometerChanged

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am new in AndEngine. I use animatedSprite and Sprite Object. I want to move Sprite on the basis of accelerometer but i dont want to move animatedSprite also. I want physicsworld implementation

```
private void addBottomFace(final float pX, final float pY) {
    myBottomSticFace = new Sprite(pX, pY, myBottomStickTextureRegion);
    myBottomStickBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.myPhysicsWorld, myBottomSticFace, BodyType.DynamicBody, myFixtureDef);

    this.myScene.attachChild(myBottomSticFace);
    this.myPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(myBottomSticFace, myBottomStickBody, true, true));
}


@Override
public void onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
    final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerometerData.getX(), pAccelerometerData.getY());
    myBottomSticFace.setPosition(myBottomSticFace,getX() + pAccelerometerData.getX(), myBottomSticFace,getY());
    Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
}
```

With this code mBottomSticFace will move according to accelerometer but body does not moves.

Comment: Your going to have to show us your code that deals with your sprite and AnimatedSprite and your physics world implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two different bodies and attach it to your sprites.
The Body you want to be moved should be set as BodyType.DynamicBody, and the other one should be BodyType.StaticBody.

To see accelerometer and body examples, check this:
http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java

Comment: I want two body of dynamic type. but i want only one of them moves from accelerometer.

Comment: What forces do you need to apply on the body that should not move with the accelerometer?

Comment: there is an Animated Sprite which i dont want to move with accelerometer. Thanks for reply but i do it by body.setLinearVelocity(gravity);                                      Now Sprite moves fine. now i want to increase weight for the sprite how can i increase the weight of the sprite